# What are passed to *args and **kwargs in hooks of requests

Tags: python, python-requests, hook

Assume now I have a simple python script like

```py
import requests
def do_something(response, *args, **kwargs):
    #do something
url = "https://example.com/get/"
resp = requests.get(url, hooks={'response':do_something})
```

My question is: what exactly are passed to `*args` and `**kwargs` when getting the response?

I didn't find the answer on [official documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#event-hooks), so if you'd like to help me I'd be appreciate.

Comment: By "official documentation" I assume you mean https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#event-hooks ? Indeed it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Each hook type has its own parameters, and many pass none at all.  You'll have to dig into the source code to get the real answer.

Comment: @TimRoberts: "Each" hook type? "Many" pass none at all? I only see one request hook, `'response'`.

Comment: @Sqr as I said it doesn't answer the question. But it's good practice to show/link to what you've found already.

Comment: Maybe you can use pycharm to run step by step

Comment: There is currently only one.  There will probably be more in the future.  It looks like it passes nothing in  `args`, and some useful information in `kwargs`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys, after reading the source code myself, I find the answer:

`args` will not be passed values.

`kwargs` is a `dict` containing information about following items:

1. time_out
2. proxies
3. stream
4. verify
5. cert

The answer could be found in `request.py`, line 582-587 and `session.py` line 671-708, at requests version 2.27.1.